# i am getting error as trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am getting sql result as array..Then it show me an error like `

> trying to get property of non-object in controller in
>   `$rate=$product_det->sale_rate;

This `sale_rate` is a field in my table product.I am new to PHP. Can anyone help?

My model:

```
function get_productDet($item)
    {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('product');
            $this->db->where('id',$item);
            $res=$this->db->get()->result_array();
            return $res;

    }
```

My controller:

```
function product_det()
    {
        $item=$this->input->post('item_id');
        $quantity=$this->input->post('quantity');
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $amount="";
        $cgst="";
        $sgst="";
        $igst="";
        $product_det=$this->sale_model->get_productDet($item);

        if(!empty($product_det))
        {
            if($rate=="" || $rate==0)
            {
                $rate=$product_det->sale_rate;
            }
            $amount=$rate*$quantity;
            $cgst_per=$product_det->CGST;
            $sgst_per=$product_det->SGST;
            $igst=0;
        }

        echo $rate."-".$amount."-".$cgst."-".$sgst."-".$igst."";

    }
```

My javascript function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>sales/product_det',
        data: ({"item_id":item_id,"quantity":quantity,"rate":rate }),
                    dataType: 'html', 
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data) 
                  {
                    alert(data);
                  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `result_array()` in your sql query.

Then use `foreach loop` to show your record like this

```
if(!empty($product_det))
    {
       foreach($product_det as $p_det){
        if($rate=="" || $rate==0)
        {
            $rate=$p_det['sale_rate'];
        }
        $amount=$rate*$quantity;
        $cgst_per=$p_det['CGST'];
        $sgst_per=$p_det['SGST'];
        $igst=0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks..Now its working...Could you please tell me how this foreach will work from converting an array?

Comment: for more detail http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Since apparently you only need details of one product.

**Change:**

```
$res=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

**To:**

```
$res=$this->db->get()->row_array();
```

Then, the result is an array not an object. To access the returned elements do the following instead.

**Change:**

```
$product_det->sale_rate;
$product_det->CGST;
$product_det->SGST;
```

**To:**

```
$product_det['sale_rate'];
$product_det['CGST']
$product_det['SGST'];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

In model just Replace

```
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

With

```
$this->db->get()->row();
```

*Your model should be like this :*

```
function get_productDet($item)
{
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('product');
      $this->db->where('id',$item);
      $res = $this->db->get()->row();
      return $res;
}
```